# Correct way to pass runtime configuration to elixir processes

Tags: configuration, elixir, runtime, gen-server

I'm trying to deploy an app to production and getting a little confused by environment and application variables and what is happening at compile time vs runtime.

In my app, I have a genserver process that requires a token to operate. So I use `config/releases.exs` to set the token variable at runtime:

```
# config/releases.exs

import Config

config :my_app, :my_token, System.fetch_env!("MY_TOKEN")
```

Then I have a bit of code that looks a bit like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.SomeService do

  use SomeBehaviour, token: Application.get_env(:my_app, :my_token),
                     other_config: :stuff

  ...

end
```

In production the genserver process (which does some http stuff) gives me 403 errors suggesting the token isn't there. So can I clarify, is the `use` keyword getting evaluated at compile time (in which case the application environment doest exist yet)?

If so, what is the correct way of getting runtime environment variables in to a service like this. Is it more correct to define the config in `application.ex` when starting the process? eg

```
children = [
  {MyApp.SomeService, [
    token: Application.get_env(:my_app, :my_token),
    other_config: :stuff
  ]}
  ...
]

Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
```

I may have answered my own questions here, but would be helpful to get someone who knows what they're doing confirm and point me in the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) has two stages: compilation and runtime, both written in *Elixir* itself. To clearly understand what happens when one should figure out, that *everything is macro* and *Elixir*, during compilation stage, expands these macros until everything is expanded. That AST comes to runtime.

In your example, `use SomeBehaviour, foo: :bar` is implicitly calling `SomeBehaviour.__using__/1` macro. To expand the AST, it requires the argument (keyword list) to be expanded as well. Hence, `Application.get_env(:my_app, :my_token)` call happens in compile time.

There are many possibilities to move it to runtime. If you are the owner of `SomeBehaviour`, make it accept the pair `{:my_app, :my_token}` and call `Application.get_env/2` somewhere from inside it.

Or, as you suggested, pass it as a parameter to `children`; this code belongs to function body, meaning it won’t be attempted to expand during compilation stage, but would rather be passed as AST to the resulting BEAM to be executed in runtime.

Comment: Thank you that is helpful. I am the owner of `SomeBehaviour`, so yes I can refactor that to accept the tuple pair like you suggested. I prefer that to my original suggestion of passing the parameters to children, as it keeps the config/setup in one place. Thanks